# Can't get Statement To Add Date and Dow

Tags: sql

This should be simple but I don't know why this wont work"
I am trying to insert into a table a date and the day of the week except Sunday. If I remove the DOW then the Statement works. The table should have 30 entries.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Declare @StartDate as Date = DateAdd(day,-30,GetDate()) 
    Declare @dateCnt as Int 
    Set @dateCnt = 0 
    While @dateCnt <= 30 
    Begin 
    Insert Into temp_ProdSaleInv (ProdDate,DOW) 
    Values(
    Convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(day,@datecnt,@startDate),101), 
    DateName(dw,DateAdd(dw,@datecnt,@startDate) 
    ) 
    Set  @dateCnt = @dateCnt + 1 
    End
```

Thanks for the help sometime you cant see the forest for the trees,

My issue is I now do not want Sundays in the table.  I add a case statement and and get a syntax error near CASE,Set and End
See below

```
Declare @StartDate as Date = DateAdd(day,-30,GetDate()) 
Declare @dateCnt as Int 
Set @dateCnt = 0 
set @DW1 as String
While @dateCnt <= 30 
@DW1 = DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(day,@dateCnt, @StartDate))
CASE WHEN @DW1 <> 'Sunday' THEN
Begin 
Insert Into temp_ProdSaleInv (ProdDate,DOW)
Values(
Convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(day,@datecnt,@startDate),101),
DateName(dw,DateAdd(dw,@datecnt,@startDate)
)
Set  @dateCnt = @dateCnt + 1 
END  
End
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a closing bracket before the `SET @datecnt = @datecnt + 1` line

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a closing bracket:

```
Declare @StartDate as Date = DateAdd(day,-30,GetDate()) 
Declare @dateCnt as Int 
Set @dateCnt = 0 
While @dateCnt <= 30 
Begin 
    Insert Into temp_ProdSaleInv (ProdDate,DOW) 
    Values(
    Convert(varchar(10),DateAdd(day,@datecnt,@startDate),101), 
    DateName(dw,DateAdd(dw,@datecnt,@startDate) 
    )) -- <<<< Here

    Set  @dateCnt = @dateCnt + 1 
End
```

Comment: @AaronDietz - Agreed. I mostly wanted to highlight where exactly the missing bracket would go. If I'd reformat the code, I'd definitely try and ensure it would be more readable as per your suggestion.